# mysql union of tables selected from another table

Tags: mysql, union

I have around 300 tables with same field types, and I have another table with a list of those 300 tables and their status. Is there a one query solution to do a union of the tables selected based on status.

Let's say each of the 300 tables has user records (id, first name, last name). And another table that has records of tables and status (table name, status code (active/inactive)). I'd like to create a union of user records from all the active tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible somehow. But why don't you just use a single table with the columns (id, first_name, last_name, table_name) ? The query would be as simple as:

```
select
  m.id, m.first_name, m.last_name
from
  mytable m inner join tables t on
  m.table_name = t.table_name
where
  t.status='Active'
```

With proper indexes it would be performant.

A solution without changing your table structure would require for example a dynamic query, but I would not recommend it:

```
select
  group_concat(
    concat('select * from ', table_name)
    separator ' union all '
  ) gc
from
  status
where
  status='Active'
into @sql;

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

(this will create a union all query into the string sql, and then it will execute it. Tables needs to be proplerly escaped, also be carefoul about group_concat size limit)

Comment: @IlyaI if you really have to use the second solution, you can change the size limit with `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;`

Comment: I have been using the first solution already, but wanted to see if it's possible to do with multiple tables. I will try the second solution. Thanks!